# How to determine how much memory a windows service should consume

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created a simple windows service that periodically checks a remote database via web-service and depending upon what it finds updates contents in a local database. Looking at the process in Task Manager it consumes anywhere between 8-MB, which seems a lot compared to what it actually does.

Is there anything that I should be checking code wise or is there anything I can run to see why it's consuming so much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even a very small C# application on Windows will have a significant memory footprint as the runtime and any used assemblies must be loaded as well.